# How do I code a discord bot not stop after a incorrect command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So anytime I send an incorrect command like !pong (where!ping is the correct one) the bot returns with the following error:

> (if(command.permissions.length){
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined

even if I remove the whole permissions code it then gives me a

TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

and it's only when I have a wrong command of that of !pong when there is no command or !me anything with the prefix that isn't a actual command. below is the code im using

Message.js

> require('dotenv').config();
>
> const cooldowns = new Map();
>
> module.exports = (Discord, client, message) =>{
> const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
> if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
>
> ```
> const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
> const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
>
> const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
> const validPermissions = [
>     "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
>     "KICK_MEMBERS",
>     "BAN_MEMBERS",
>     "ADMINISTRATOR",
>     "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
>     "MANAGE_GUILD",
>     "ADD_REACTIONS",
>     "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
>     "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
>     "STREAM",
>     "VIEW_CHANNEL",
>     "SEND_MESSAGES",
>     "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
>     "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
>     "EMBED_LINKS",
>     "ATTACH_FILES",
>     "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
>     "MENTION_EVERYONE",
>     "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
>     "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
>     "CONNECT",
>     "SPEAK",
>     "MUTE_MEMBERS",
>     "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
>     "MOVE_MEMBERS",
>     "USE_VAD",
>     "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
>     "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
>     "MANAGE_ROLES",
>     "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
>     "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
>   ]
>
>   if(command.permissions.length){
>     let invalidPerms = []
>     for(const perm of command.permissions){
>       if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
>         return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
>       }
>       if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
>         invalidPerms.push(perm);
>       }
>     }
>     if (invalidPerms.length){
>       return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
>     }
>   }
>
>
>
> if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
>     cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
> }
>
> const current_time = Date.now();
> const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
> const cooldown_ammount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;
>
> if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
>     const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_ammount;
>
>     if(current_time < expiration_time){
>         const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
>
>         return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`)
>     }
> }
>
> time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
> setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_ammount);
>
> try{
>     command.execute(message,args, cmd, client, Discord);
> } catch (err){
>     message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
>     console.log(err);
> }
>  }
> ```

ping.js

> module.exports = {
> name: 'ping',
> cooldown: 10,
> permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES",],
> description: "this is a ping command!",
> execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord){
> message.channel.send('pong!');
> } }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined for my commands and a TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined for other commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68294383/typeerror-cannot-read-property-send-of-undefined-for-my-commands-and-a-typeer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your message.js, after the declaration of `command`, you need to check if it’s undefined or null

```js
const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
if(!command) return;
```

Edit: your error comes from here:

```js
command.execute(message,args, cmd, client, Discord);
//^^how you execute
execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord){ message.channel.send('pong!'); }
//^^how you define it
```

So as you can see, you put them in the wrong order.

Comment: thank you that worked, I must have deleted it when I added the permissions code because it worked then, but now I have a different problem (Which ill look up when I get home to see if I forgot to add something else or not) now the new error is
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" again I probably forgot to add something or deleted something needed

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it did work.

Comment: Also I found the fix to your new error, please check the edit I made to the answer

Comment: the 2nd command did not fix the error it now has expecting a "," in the code for command.execute and the ; at the end